# Using ADO/DAO Connection to Download data from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access

I am trying to figure out how to download using an ADO/DAO connection in Access VBA to get the contents of a table from SQL server. I am trying to avoid using a linked table because the DB requires a password and I keep running into issues with getting it to not ask for the login info. Are there any ideas or references for me to start with on this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears either way you'll need to provide SQL credentials.

There's more involved without linking a table, basically you'd want a recordset for the source and the "target" table to iterate over.

```
targetrs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Target", dbOpenTable)

Dim Con As New ADODB.Connection
Dim sqlStr As String 
    Con.Open _
        "Provider = sqloledb;" & _
        "Data Source=SqlServer;" & _
        "Initial Catalog=MyDB;" & _
        "User ID=sa;" & _
        "Password=p@ssW0rd;"

Dim rsSource As New ADODB.Recordset 
    rsSource.Open "select * from SOURCE", Con

    do until rsSource.eof
        targetrs.addnew
        for each field in rsSource
            targetrs.fields(field.Name) = rsSource.fields(field.Name)
        next
        targetrs.update
        rssource.movenext
    loop
```

*Since you still have to have the credentials, you could dynamically link the table instead:*

```
docmd.TransferDatabase acLink,"ODBC Database",
"ODBC;Driver={SQL Server};Server=MySQLServer;Database=MYSQLDB;
Uid=USER;Pwd=PASSWORD",acTable,"SQLtable","MyAccessTable"
```

Comment: So where do I input the table the data is to be downloaded to and vice-versa?

Comment: In the Access database, but with my short example, you'll be required they have the same fields.  You could link the table like you have, then do a copy, and afterwards paste only the structure.  Also, you'd want to do a "Delete from Target" before this code.  Personal opinion, since you have to have the credentials either way, the dynamic link may involve less code.

Answer (score 1):

Use of a linked table does not require you store or have the user password in that linked table.

If you execute a SINGLE logon at application startup then all linked tables will work.

Linked tables work WITHOUT a prompt for user or password.

Linked tables work WITHOUT you having to store the user ID or password in the link.

Access will cache the user name + password if you logon as per the instructions here:

http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2011/04/08/power-tip-improve-the-security-of-database-connections.aspx

So to download a table to a local, then you ONLY need this code:

For a new local table (create table query):

```
CurrentDb.Execute "SELECT * INTO LocalTableCreate FROM ServerTable"
```

Append to existing table:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO LocalTable SELECT * FROM ServerTable"
```

And if some really strange reason and desire exists create and promote world poverty and do things the hard way like a turtle with time to waste and not use a linked table?

Well you could create a linked table via the “transfer database” command. It is only one extra line of code in front of the above code and then AGAIN the above two examples would work fine.

However I see little if any advantage to creating + deleting a linked table.

I suppose for reasons of performance or perhaps for security or the legitimate reason of you not knowing the table ahead of time? Then I would suggest you use a saved a pass-though query as performance will be even faster.

So you can use this code:

```
Dim qdfPass       As DAO.QueryDef 
Set qdfPass = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MyPass") 
qdfPass.SQL = "select * from dbo.MyTable;" 


CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO LocalTable SELECT * FROM MyPass”
```

Note that the sql used in above qerydef MUST be native T-SQL and can be a view or even a store procedure like:

```
qdfPass.SQL = "exec sp_myCoolStoreProc;"
```

And the stored procedure can even be passed a parameter like this:

```
qdfPass.SQL = "exec sp_myCoolStoreProc " & strMyParam
```

and then :

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO LocalTable SELECT * FROM MyPass”
```

So we can even use a select into/append from a store procedure by doing the above and the table/sql server side is dynamic or can even be a stored procedure. Again VERY little code.

I would suggest you avoid the idea proposed here to write recordset looping code unless one really has the desire to write looping code when none is required. And things like PK would have to be dealt with separate in code if you use such loops since the local pk column may need to be skipped (you simply leave that column out of the select SQL).

Note again that the connection string saved for the pass-though query does NOT require the user ID and password by using the above link showing how to “logon” to SQL Server. And if the table is known, then again a saved table link or pass-though query will suffice here.

Comment: So where would I write this in access, would I write it in my startup macros?

Comment: And the reason I am not using a linked table is because, if there is no connection the queries that are made up of the linked tables where this data is being accessed from do not run properly and deletes the MAKE TABLE table that is a result of the linked tables.

Comment: You been asking about code and posting code here and all of a sudden out of the blue you are now are asking where we put such code? I cannot read your mind but this code would “presumably” be placed in the SAME location as all your previous code that you wanted to run. A “wild” and speculative guess would thus suggest such code would be placed behind a button that a user clicks on when they want to transfer the data between the two systems. Before asking this question when and how did you want this code to run?

Comment: If there is no connection then NONE OF YOUR example code will work either. As I stated if YOUR examples as posted don’t have a connection then they will also fail. So as I stated in BOTH cases and in fact in ALL cases if you don’t have a connection then the transfer cannot occur. The fact of having a linked table or not does not change the fact that a transfer cannot work without an existing connection. As I stated the connection is not used until you transfer anyway and thus linked tables changes nothing here. Testing for valid connection is required in all cases included linked tables or not